# how to organize randomly placed divs on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a page which on load places the divs randomly over a page.
these divs are also draggable.

i would like to introduce a link on this page that organizes these divs automatically

i put all my code on this jsfiddle, although it doesn't seem to work (it does work on my page though)

http://www.jsfiddle.net/BbKsq/

i really don't understand jsfiddle sorry

hope someone can help me out here, thanks!!

```
$("#web01").each(function() {
    var randHigh = Math.floor(Math.random()*($(window).height() -200));
    var randWide = Math.floor(Math.random()*($(window).width() -200));
    $(this).css({'top': randHigh});
    $(this).css({'left': randWide});
```

Comment: Your fiddle has an extra `});` which is why it's not working - it works fine for me if I remove that. See http://jsfiddle.net/BbKsq/2/

Comment: It's not a good idea to reuse the same ID twice. Better use classes instead.

Comment: Side note: `ID`s ***MUST*** be unique!

Answer (score 0):

You should use classes if you want to organize several "similar" divs. The ID is usually used to differntiate a unique element.

If you move to that, then you can reorganize all the divs with the same class without much problems, then you can add a button that performs a javscript function that organize some (or all) of the divs with the class that you choose.

Hope this helps